# Strange error on Mumbai's polygonscan

Tags: etherscan, addresses, arrays, web3-providers

I have a write function to add an array of addresses, I put for example this:

> ["0xddC5f73aB04FbcE9fF79AA07D0A4196BD0285f46"]

And the polygon scan (not metamask), says this error:

> invalid address (arg="addresses", coderType="address", value="0xddC5f73aB04FbcE9fF79AA07D0A4196BD0285f46"")

Check how it adds at and a " at the end. Any ideas what is happening? All the other write functions work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems to be a bug in polygonscan.

Comment: And what is my recourse?, to interact with the contract from Remix?

Comment: You could report to polygonscan support and wait for it to fix it, or use another wallet that support interacting with a contract. I think MyEtherWallet does support, but I'm not sure if they support polygon network, another alternative is using Remix+Metamask.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is valid, try to submit the tx with ethersjs or web3.